# Is there a way to use the same ID multiple times using CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
<p id = "formatOne">My text here</p>
<!--insert bunch of other stuff in between-->

<!--Reuse formatOne so I don't have to copy-paste the entire CSS formatting again for each use
(similar to functions in most programming languages, write once, call whenever-->

<p id = "formatOne">Different text here</p> <!--like this, but this is obviously wrong since ID must be unique-->
```

Is there a way to make CSS ID's that are callable like functions?

Comment: Is [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) what you are looking for ?

Answer (score -1):

`id` should be unique per HTML element. If you want to apply same style to different HTML elements, you can create `class` and apply the same class to multiple HTML elements.

```css
.formatOne {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="formatOne">My text here</p>
<p class="formatOne">Different text here</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible with ids. If you want same multiple uses in css then only class
allow you to do so.

```
<body>
<div class="asd">
    <h1> First </h1>
    <p> First line Statement </p>
</div>
<div class="asd">
    <h1> Second </h1>
    <p> Second line Statement </p>
</div>
<style>

.asd {color : red;
      font-size: 20px}

</style>
</body>
```